# How do I install mongodb in Google Colab with the new Ubuntu 22.04 update?

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, google, mongodb

I want to access my mongodb server within Google Colab. For this, I have to install and run mongodb within Google Colab.

With the new Ubuntu 22.04 update I am unable to get this to work.

Has anybody found a good work around?

I tried many installations and none have been working. What has worked for other people? !sudo service mongodb start Always results in mongodb: unrecognized service